# How to find the caller of a method that I set a breakpoint in?

Tags: flash-builder, breakpoints

I have couple of classes and tens of methods around. At some point the program goes to a line in one of the methods(function A)-which is unexpected. When I set up a breakpoint, it is clear that there is a caller here and directs program to that method(A). The only method(function B) calls A and it is commented. And I need to find the caller/directing line. So is there a way to find caller line?

Note: I am using Adobe Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0):

That unexpected call sounds wierd as you say, since the unique method that calls it is commented.

If you are debugging the application find the caller stack and you should have there all the callers from the execution beginning.

Regards.